# Простая разметка

Tags: android, android-layout

Нужно сделать разметку следующего вида. Затруднения вызывает компонент 2, каким образом его можно растянуть на весь экран, но так чтобы его не перекрывали компоненты 3 и 4. Код писать не нужно, нужна просто идея.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без кода объяснить не смогу, к сожалению. Но вы из этого кода попробуйте достать идею)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- Элемент 1 -->
    <!-- 60dp в качестве примера высоты контента -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#00FF00" />
    <!-- Элемент 2 -->
    <!-- Занимаем весь экран, оставляя место для одного элемента -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFF00" />
    <!-- Элемент (лэйаут) 3 -->
    <!-- Под него выделено место. В нём находятся элементы 3 и 4 -->
    <!-- Элементы 3 и 4 занимают 50% ширины (всего 100% - атрибут weightSum) -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FF0000" >
        <!-- Занимаем 50% ширины -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Элемент 3" />
        <!-- Занимаем 50% ширины -->
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Элемент 4" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Результат**
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Отличное решение. Мой код был абсолютно таким же, кроме тега android:layout_weight="1".

Answer (score 0):

TableRow в помощь